# Wordpress install fails : Fatal Error: Uncaught

Tags: wordpress

I'm having an issue installing civicrm against a WordPress install.  Plugin is installed.  wp-content>uploads>civicrm is present, writable, and empty.  I have specified a separate database to use.  However, I was encountering the same issue when I tried to install against the WP database.  This is the error I am receiving:

---

### Fatal error: Uncaught Civi\Setup\Exception\SqlException: Cannot execute CREATE TABLE `civicrm_extension` ( `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Local Extension ID', `type` varchar(8) NOT NULL , `full_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Fully qualified extension name', `name` varchar(255) COMMENT 'Short name', `label` varchar(255) COMMENT 'Short, printable name', `file` varchar(255) COMMENT 'Primary PHP file', `schema_version` varchar(63) COMMENT 'Revision code of the database schema; the format is module-defined', `is_active` tinyint DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'Is this extension active?' , PRIMARY KEY (`id`) , UNIQUE INDEX `UI_extension_full_name`( full_name ) , INDEX `UI_extension_name`( name ) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes in /var/www/vhosts/******.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/ in /var/www/vhosts/******.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/setup/src/Setup/DbUtil.php on line 204

Any thoughts on where to start? Happy to provide any info needed to help troubleshoot.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SE CiviCRM

You will need the following MySQL server configuration:

```
innodb_large_prefix=true 
innodb_file_format=barracuda 
innodb_file_per_table=true
```

add above configuration in your [my.cnf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2485758) file.

See [mysql requirement](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements/#mysql-configuration) for CiviCRM

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response.  I'll try that now.  Much appreciated :)